# Where is Createsamples.exe? - OpenCV Windows

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a sample project in Opencv. I have created the text file which contains the points of imag using objectmarker. Now I need Createsamples.exe to create vector file. But there`s no such file in 'opencv' folder. Theres only createsample.cpp file. Please help me how to go about it guys..

Comment: You will probably need to compile that yourself.

Comment: When i try to compile it in a existing project.. I am getting an error " fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:" Eventhough I linked the header in the "Additional Include Directories"

Comment: did you find it? I am also looking fo rit..

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to download and install the OpenCV distribution [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/?source=navbar).
Building it from the cpp source gave me errors too.

`createsamples.exe` will be in the following path: `\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin`

Comment: This bounty is totally worth it I guess. I am on Windows. I disagree with some of the other answers here. This solved my problem after hours!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why a bounty has been added to this question, Yuu's answer is very close to being correct with a few modifications:

The executable is not called `createsamples.exe` in newer versions of OpenCV. With any default download and installation of a current version of OpenCV you will be able to navigate to the install folder, for me the right folder is:

`C:\libraries\opencv\build\install\x86\vc15\bin`

and inside this folder you will find both debug and release versions of the executable:

- 'opencv_createsamples.exe - release
- opencv_createsamplesd.exe - debug

**Update 1.0**

For completness sake I have just downloaded and installed a default version of V3.4.0 from [here](https://opencv.org/releases.html). All I did was download, and install and you can find `opencv_createsamples.exe` here:

- {MyChosenInstallFolder}\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin
- {MyChosenInstallFolder}\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin

It does not provide debug executables.

**Update 2.0**

I have just completed the same download and install for the most recent V2.X and you can find 'opencv_createsamples.exe' here:

- {MyChosenInstallFolder}\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin
- {MyChosenInstallFolder}\opencv\build\x86\vc14\bin

You can see that only VC14 libs are created with 2.X & VC15 & VC14 X64 for V3.X

Comment: Needs another update as it's not included in 4.6 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Small detail for OpenCV 4.X on windows, the `opencv_createsamples` program was removed du to porting from C to C++. So if you download this version, you WON'T find it. However, according to this https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231#issuecomment-465621445 you can use these specific program from 3.4 in your 4.3 install

Answer (score -2):

Look for the file `opencv_createsamples.exe`.
By default it should be in

`<opencv-dir>/build/bin` or

`<opencv-dir>/build/bin/Release`.

Comment: I have searched completly.. There is not even one exe file is there in open cv folder..